# Running a VBA Excel Macro and getting screen flickering even after rightly setting Application.ScreenUpdating to True and False

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro which is quite big and has several `Sub` functions. The macro pulls external data and perform Calculations on them and produces results on the sheet along with a graph.

The problem is that the macro runs absolutely fine with smaller data. But when I pull a databank of say 1500 entries, the screen starts flickering and the program hangs. It doesn't even give any error message.

Had it been any faults in loop, the program shouldn't have worked for 200 entries. But it does for a lot of datas except the very long ones. Also the size of arrays used are set up to 2000, and `Application.ScreenUpdating` has been turned `False` at the start and `True` at the end in every `Sub`.

Another important information as to how the program works:

The codes are connected to a Userform. So if one optionbutton and another entry is true, a particular process (`Sub`) is happening one at a time. So for each sub I have given `Application.ScreenUpdating` as `False` and `True`. Technically out of 15 subs, perhaps only 5 are running at a time in a module. I have kept every case in the same module as it is easier to handle that way. However, few subs run at a time.

Comment: you should have (rather) only one `ScreenUpdating = false` and one line which set it to `true` (some exceptions are possible). Each time you trigger `Screenupdating = true` you refresh Excel which is not what you want here. Do you use `Debug.Print` to trace progress of your code running? you should to check when it stops and if it really does.

Comment: KazimierzJawor: well the thing is, the codes are connected to Userform. So if one optionbutton and another entry is filled a particular process (Sub) is happening one at a time. So for each sub I have given screen update. Technically out of 15 subs, perhaps only 5 are running at a time in a module. Do you still advice to just give one screen update?

Comment: this information should be added to your question as it is extremely important in your situation. please change your question.

Comment: Based on KazimierzJawor's comment the solution is commenting out all of the `Screenupdating = True` lines. Once the processes are done you regain control anyways.

Comment: I have understood why my program didnt work. The problem was actually sadly with the database. i got a wrong kind of database which wasn't meant for my logic. Now my program works fine.!!